# Move django-celery-monitor functionality to the site

Tags: python, django

How can i move django-celery-monitor functionality to the site-page? Main functions of this app are in admin-site, but i need this into my site.
In the beginning, I tried to display the model on the site. But even this could not be done.

```
# view.py
from django_celery_monitor.models import TaskState
class MonViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = TaskState
    list_display = ('task_id', 'state', 'name', 'args', 'kwargs', 'eta', 'runtime', 'worker')
    ordering = ('name',)
    filter_fields = ('name',)

# url.py
url('^mon/', include(views.MonViewSet().urls)),
```

It raise the exception - namespace not register. Then i tried to add some string into my template, like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'bgp_app:mon' %}">{% trans 'Monitor' %}</a></li>
```

But this raise the exception to this string. I think, that there is more simple way to do what i need.
I use Django 1.11, Celery Monitoring for Django 1.1.2.